# MySQL returning only 1 row, multiple entries in the database

Tags: mysql

I am creating a list of all publications for employees, and I am currently stuck on a query.  It runs with no syntactical errors, but it only returns one row.  The ERD for the relevant tables is as follows:

[image]

There is a many-to-many relationship between publications and employees, publications publication tags, and publications and publication types.  Each publication *must* have at least one tag and one type.

**The Query**

```
SELECT publicationsId, title, summary, image, publicationDate, citation, dateAdded, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tagName) AS tagName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT publicationType) AS publicationType, employee_employeeId
FROM publications
LEFT JOIN publications_have_publicationTags ON publications_have_publicationTags.publications_publicationsId = publications.publicationsId
LEFT JOIN publicationTags ON publications_have_publicationTags.publicationTags_publicationTagId = publicationTags.publicationTagId
LEFT JOIN publications_have_publicationTypes ON publications.publicationsId = publications_have_publicationTypes.publications_publicationsId
LEFT JOIN publicationTypes ON publications_have_publicationTypes.publicationTypes_publicationTypeId = publicationTypes.publicationTypeId
LEFT JOIN employee_has_publications ON publications.publicationsId = employee_has_publications.publications_publicationsId
ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

**Extra Info**

I was originally using `INNER JOIN` with the same effect.  I'm using `PDO` on the website, but I get the same result when running the query in phpmyadmin.

How can I get the publications information, and their related tags and types in one query?  Or should I just run separate queries to eliminate the complexity?

Comment: For one row issue you can use `GROUP BY employee_employeeId` before order by

Comment: I'm not trying to limit the rows, it's not getting them as is.

Comment: My apologies @MKhalidJunaid, it appears that you were correct.  I didn't think it would have that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `select` statement includes `group_concat()`.  This is an aggregation function.  Because there is no `group by`, this means that all the rows are treated as one group, and hence one row is returned.

Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT publicationsId, title, summary, image, publicationDate, citation, dateAdded,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tagName) AS tagName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT publicationType) AS publicationType,
       employee_employeeId
FROM publications
LEFT JOIN publications_have_publicationTags ON publications_have_publicationTags.publications_publicationsId = publications.publicationsId
LEFT JOIN publicationTags ON publications_have_publicationTags.publicationTags_publicationTagId = publicationTags.publicationTagId
LEFT JOIN publications_have_publicationTypes ON publications.publicationsId = publications_have_publicationTypes.publications_publicationsId
LEFT JOIN publicationTypes ON publications_have_publicationTypes.publicationTypes_publicationTypeId = publicationTypes.publicationTypeId
LEFT JOIN employee_has_publications ON publications.publicationsId = employee_has_publications.publications_publicationsId
GROUP BY publicationsId, title, summary, image, publicationDate, citation, dateAdded, emplyee_employeeid
ORDER BY dateAdded DESC;
```

Comment: Nailed it, many thanks!  There's a minor typo on the `GROUP BY` line, on employee, but fixed and ran and it's coming up as expected.